# Projection on space of permutations of lower diagonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $G$ be the group of all $n\times n$ permutation matrices and let $V$ be the vector space of all $n$-dimensional lower diagonal matrices. Then I define the set
$$
X = \{P\cdot L\cdot P^T \mid \forall P\in G, L\in V\},
$$
where "$\cdot$'' is matrix multiplication. That is, $X$ is the set of all lower diagonal matrices with possible rows and colums that are permuted at the same time.

> I am interested in the orthogonal projection of a general matrix $M\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ on the set $X\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Does anyone know if there is a more efficient method to do it than projecting on each space
>   $$
>  V_P = \{P\cdot L\cdot P^T \mid \forall L\in V\}
> $$
>   for every individual $P\in G$ and then taking the shortest one?

Thank you in advance!